# Expectation of a random variable $X$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, expected-value

9 people are assigned to one of 17 posts uniformly at random and more than one person can be at one post. Letting $X$ be the random variable representing the number of occupied posts, I was tasked with computing the expectation.

For my sample space $\Omega$, I was thinking of doing tuples where a person is mapped to one of the 17 posts with $|\Omega|=17^{9}$ (by stars and bars).

From here on I'm always confused with expectation. Would it be beneficial to utilize indicator random variables or do I have all I need to solve this?

Comment: You cannot use stars and bars for this problem.  Stars and bars are good for counting how to assign indistinguishable balls into distinguishable boxes.  But here the people are distinguishable, and the same space has size $17^9$ (and every sample point is equally likely).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is simplest to use indicator random variables and the linearity of expectation.

Let $X_i$ equal one if post $i$ is occupied and zero otherwise.  $X$, the count of occupied posts is then the sum of the seventeen indicators. $$\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E(\sum_{i=1}^{17}X_i)$$